# Dropdown z-index can't be updated

Tags: sass, z-index

I am working on Angular, and now I have problem with dropdown z-index issue. 
When I inspect in chrome, there is a new class called ***dropdown***.
In this dropdown class there some information include z-index (z-index: 1050).
However, there is no ***dropdown class*** found in my html file and the whole project as well.

```css
.dropdown {
  z-index: 1052;
  background-color: red;
}
```

I updated my scss code with dropdown class, and it changed color to red, but z-index is not change to 1052.
Note: position of dropdown is absolute.

Can anyone help or suggest me how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Can you please share more details?

Comment: Thank you @Heena Vora. I have a dropdown on a pop-up. When I click dropdown to display a list, dropdown list hide behind the pop-up. As I inspect in chrome, the dropdown has z-index = 1050. After change it to 1052, it could display over the pop-up as usual. As mention in the question above, I tried to change the value of z-index of dropdown in scss file, but it doesn't work. It worked with background-property, but not work with z-index. I wonder if there is anyway to make z-index value change.

Comment: This is happening (almost for sure) because of some other class have more specificioty than yours and its winning, thus, its "overwriting" your class declaration. In order to help, please, give us your css code.

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: I think my code are related to other components that not related to the question.  Now I have found a way to make it work. but just add `!important` set the most priority to `z-index` property. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown {
  z-index: 1052 !important;
  background-color: red;
}
```

It works now!
Just add `!important` to set z-index value.
Maybe `!important` help z-index value that set here overwrite to its default value???